# SQL Server 2016 + Linked Server Join = Row not returned

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm querying on SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT 1
FROM LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE1 A with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE2 B with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE3 C with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE4 D with (nolock) ON (D.FIELD1 = C.FIELD1 AND D.CHAR_FIELD2 = B.VARCHAR_FIELD2 AND (D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD3 OR D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD4))
WHERE B.FIELD5 IN ('4472')
```

**Result: Row is not returned**

1 - If I change the condition **AND D.CHAR_FIELD2 = B.VARCHAR_FIELD2** outside of the join:

```
SELECT 1
FROM LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE1 A with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE2 B with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE3 C with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE4 D with (nolock) ON (D.FIELD1 = C.FIELD1 AND (D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD3 OR D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD4))
WHERE B.FIELD5 IN ('4472')
AND D.CHAR_FIELD2 = B.VARCHAR_FIELD2
```

**Result: Row is returned**

2 - If I remove the linked server on **TABLE4**:

```
SELECT 1
FROM LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE1 A with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE2 B with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE3 C with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 D with (nolock) ON (D.FIELD1 = C.FIELD1 AND D.CHAR_FIELD2 = B.VARCHAR_FIELD2 AND (D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD3 OR D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD4))
WHERE B.FIELD5 IN ('4472')
```

**Result: Row is returned**

3 - If I run the same query on SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT 1
FROM LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE1 A with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE2 B with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE3 C with (nolock) ON ...
LEFT JOIN LINKEDSERVER1.DATABASE1.DBO.TABLE4 D with (nolock) ON (D.FIELD1 = C.FIELD1 AND D.CHAR_FIELD2 = B.VARCHAR_FIELD2 AND (D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD3 OR D.FIELD3 = B.FIELD4))
WHERE B.FIELD5 IN ('4472')
```

**Result: Row is returned**

I'm running SQL Server 2016 13.0.1601.5.
I couldn't find anything about this on SP1 and SP2.

Is this a known issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are all the joins actually on the same server (`LINKEDSERVER1`)? Troubleshooting the issue is relatively simple in this case -- compare execution plans for the query on the originating and the destination server to see what's going on. If all the joins concern the same server, SQL Server should be able to push the entire query down to the remote server, instead of doing anything locally. The collation of the source server, or the "collation compatible" setting, shouldn't matter in this case, but you might want to check those anyway.

Comment: Note that if you *are* joining together only remote tables from one server, it's a better idea to make the remote server entirely responsible for the whole query, by packaging things up in a sproc and using `EXECUTE AT`, using a view that takes care of the joins, or using an `OPENQUERY`. Alternatively, pre-emptively pull or push data into temp tables using `INSERT INTO`. Generally, you want to be in control of what data is processed where, because the default choices of the engine can leave much to be desired (in terms of performance, not usually correctness).

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help. No, they are not on the same server, but I have both databases in a test server. I've already checked for collation and they are the same. I don't use only tables from the same database, I simplified the query to post, that's why the linked server. About execution plan, local query returns 4 rows for TABLE4,remote returns only 3 rows

Comment: Without trawling through all the release notes for all the SPs and CUs (there've been a few too many for me to do that), you're on RTM, and this may still be an optimizer bug fixed in a later version. If you have the option, upgrade to the latest version (SP2 CU3 -- well, actually, SQL Server 2017 CU11, but that's another major). You can also try if the previous version of the optimizer helps (activated by downgrading the DB compat level, or using `TRACEOFF(4199)`. There's also `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` (combined with a plan guide if you can't modify the original query).

Comment: Found the problem. I was checking the fields' collation, but the databases default collations are different. I guess that because the fields are char and varchar, it is casting one of then and using default collation, then when remote query is executed, it doesn't find the record. If I change default collation or force field collation, it works. If I disable "Use Remote Collation" on then linked server properties, it works too.

Comment: Consider posting that as an answer, in case someone else runs into the same issue. The database collation being the problem is not such an obvious failure mode.

Comment: Did it, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was checking the fields' collation, but the databases default collations are different.

I guess that because the fields are char and varchar, it is casting one of then and using default collation, then when remote query is executed, it doesn't find the record.

If I change default collation or force field collation, it works. If I disable "Use Remote Collation" on then linked server properties, it works too.